# Heating Issue In Nissan Sunny

Tags: engine, cooling

I have a Nissan sunny N16 car which heats(engine) at a low speed but normalizes at high speed and when its on idle the temperature stays normal.

Need Solution?

Comment: Check the thermostat operation. But your question needs clarification - is it the engine T or cabin heater that have issues?

Comment: Is it the mottor heats up then normalizes or your heat inside from heater.If my air conditioner is on my runs a little warmer .

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  As Mike asked, is it the heater fan inside the car that is having problems, or is it the engine coolant temperature (the gauge on your dash)  that is acting strangely?  Also, what do you mean by "at the starting point it stays on its normal temperature"? -- Could you clarify?  Thanks!

Comment: its the engine coolant temperature which is playing up. I have change the water pump and engine coolant unit still it does the same.

Comment: its the engine coolant temperature which is playing up. I have change the water pump and engine coolant unit still it does the same

Comment: Did you change thermostat ? Try going lower heat thermostat. Sensor for gauge probably getting a hoter reading when waiting on thermostat to open. Just a thought hope you get it fixed.ive got a Rav 4 runs hot all Time without thermostat.

Comment: Did you change tempature sensor.  You ever take radiator cap off when it's cold hold your hand and flat over it get some one to start it see if any kind of pressure ? just curious about something .water level maybe droping down off sensor causing false read on guage going to ground cold  back to normal warm.  Just hope you can find it

Answer (score -1):

Best answer is you kindly check the engine oil you are using for your car is suitable for your engine in your region. As engine oil characteristic in viscosity varies with temperature and altitude you are using it. I am hoping the you are riding your car in Indian roads. With popularity of this car on plains is higher than the mountains sepically in southern Indian markets. The recommended engine oil should be at least 10w -40 in summer/ winter or 15w -40 if your car is driving on regions where temperature goes 45+ easily or close to it for most of the year. Still I would say one more thing please refer your user manual which you get with the car. And ask your car company. to help you with the selecting the grade of engine oil as per the terrain your are driving your car. please do consider one thing 5w-30/ 5w-40 are meant for extreme cold weather areas and are not good in high temperate regions.
Most of the mechanics will encourage you to buy 5w-xx stock because of less knowledge or to make profit out of it.
But, its your engine which takes the load of the not appropriate engine oil you give to the car.I do hope this will help you cool down your car issues.